# Instruments Trace Error : Target failed to run: The operation couldn’t be completed. (FBSOpenApplicationErrorDomain

Tags: xcode, instruments

Running Instruments from the command line gave me this error:

```
Instruments Trace Error : Target failed to run: The operation couldn’t be completed. (FBSOpenApplicationErrorDomain error 8.) : Failed to launch process with bundle identifier
```

Any idea what the problem is and how to fix?

Comment: Getting the same thing today on iOS8.3 trying to profile allocations

Answer (score 10):

In my case I believe it was a provisioning profile issue. Try going into Product/Scheme/Edit Scheme and changing the Profile build configuration from Release to Debug or vice versa - that got it working for me.

Comment: Worked for me by changing Release to Debug in "Profile", Thanks!!